# How to find indefinite integral

Tags: integration

Im trying to find this indefinite integral:

$$\int \frac{5x^2+4x-4}{(x+1)(x^2-4)}dx$$

I thought of using Partial fractions and got to

$$5x^2+4x+4 = x^2(A+B+C)+x(-B+3C)-4A-2B+2C.$$

Now I have $3$ system of equations:
\begin{eqnarray}
A+B+C=5\\  
-B+3C=4\\  
-4A-2B+2C=4  
\end{eqnarray}
But I'm not sure how to solve for any of the variable above, I was thinking of solving for B first but I'm not sure.

Comment: I solved for A, B, and C, as A = -5/3, B = 4, and C = 8/3

Comment: Then I solved for the integral and got my answer as -5/3Ln|x+1|+4Ln|x+2|+83Ln|x-2|, I think that is right.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\frac{5x^2+4x-4}{(x+1)(x^2-4)}dx=\int\frac{4x^2+4x+x^2-4}{(x+1)(x^2-4)}dx=$$
$$=\int\frac{4x^2+4x}{(x+1)(x^2-4)}dx+\int\frac{x^2-4}{(x+1)(x^2-4)}dx=$$
$$=\int\frac{4x(x+1)}{(x+1)(x^2-4)}dx+\int\frac{1}{x+1}dx=$$
$$=\int\frac{4x}{x^2-4}dx+\int\frac{1}{x+1}dx=$$
$$=2\int\frac{2x}{x^2-4}dx+\int\frac{1}{x+1}dx=...$$

Answer (score 2):

Using partial fractions as you say, we get $$\int\frac{5x^2+4x-4}{(x+1)(x-2)(x+2)}\;dx=\int\left(\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{x-2}+\frac{C}{x+2}\right)\; dx.$$

Setting the integrands equal and multiplying by the denominator on the left gives

$5x^2+4x-4=A(x-2)(x+2)+B(x+1)(x+2)+C(x+1)(x-2)$.

Letting $x=2$ yields $24=12B$, so $B=2$.

Letting $x=-2$ yields $8=4C$, so $C=2$.

Letting $x=-1$ yields $-3=-3A$, so $A=1$.

(Now substitute back into the partial fractions and integrate each term.)